# every 4 image clear

Tags: php, css

I have a bunch of images; I need to float them left and every 4 image clear them and go to the next row (like a table):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo "<img src='" . base_url('/images/question.jpg') . "' alt='Smiley face' height='65' width='65' id='" . ($i-1 ) . "' class='guess last_in_row'><div class='img_container last_in_row'></div>";
    } else {
        echo "<img src='" . base_url('/images/question.jpg') . "' alt='Smiley face' height='65' width='65' id='" . ($i-1 ) . "' class='guess '><div class='img_container'></div>";
    }
}
```

I tried a lot but I could not get the desired output: my last try was:

```
.guess{
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.last_in_row:after{
        clear: left;

}
```

[Fiddle with the rendered HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/6Np55/)

Comment: Code looks okay to me.  What does the output look like?  BTW, "&& $i!=0" is probably not necessary since you start $i at 1 in the loop!

Comment: You see the result in my fiddle

Comment: I'm at work, and we're stuck with I.E. 8, so the fiddle doesn't work. Sorry I can't help debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a pure CSS solution you could use [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type) pseudo-class like `:nth-of-type(4n+1)` to apply `clear: left;` CSS declaration to every `4`th image element starting from `1`:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6Np55/1/)**

```css
#images img:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Where the spec states:

> **[6.6.5.4. :nth-of-type() pseudo-class](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#nth-of-type-pseudo)**
>
> The `:nth-of-type(an+b)` pseudo-class notation represents an element
>   that has `an+b-1` siblings with the same expanded element name before it
>   in the document tree, for any zero or positive integer value of `n`, and
>   has a parent element. See [`:nth-child()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#nth-child-pseudo) pseudo-class for the syntax of
>   its argument. It also accepts the ‘even’ and ‘odd’ values.

It's worth noting that `:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class [is supported in **IE9+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: +1. Beat me to it. This is what I'd do, too. Much more elegant than a PHP solution.

Comment: @Hashem +1 too; I liked your code; Amal But your code works in my case; becasue in the container I'm adding images dynamically with Jquery and it breaks the rule! Thanks to both of you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code,

PHP:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo "<img src='" . base_url('/images/question.jpg') . "' alt='Smiley face' height='65' width='65' id='" . ($i-1 ) . "' class='guess'><div class='img_container last_in_row'></div>";
    } else {
        echo "<img src='" . base_url('/images/question.jpg') . "' alt='Smiley face' height='65' width='65' id='" . ($i-1 ) . "' class='guess'>";
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.guess{
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.last_in_row{
        clear: both;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Less elegant than the CSS solution, here is what I would do in PHP:

```
for($i=1;$i<=24;$i++)
{
   echo "<img src='".base_url('/images/question.jpg')."' alt='Smiley face' height='65' width='65' id='".($i-1)."' class='guess'>";
   if($i % 4 == 0)
   {
      echo "<div class='last_in_row'></div>";
   }
}
```

With this CSS code:

```
.guess {
   float:left;
}
.last_in_row {
   clear:both;
}
```